# Meaning of _(' ') in php and what inside it?

Tags: php

I was reading and learning a code and I found this code,  infoBookingsTitle shows the title of the page, which is "Reservation options", I tried to found this file to edit the "Reservation options" word with something else but I didn't know where should I look, like what is that a PHP file, class or what?

```
          <div>

          <h2>   <?php __('infoBookingsTitle') ?>  </h2>

          </div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: It's a function named `__`.  It's probably for translations.

Comment: so, I can find infoBookingsTitle on a php file right?

Comment: It's part of Wordpress or some other framework. not from PHP.

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/__/ or https://api.cakephp.org/3.3/function-__.html

Comment: No, the translation file will be a binary file, but there will also be a template file... a .pot I think

Comment: Thank you soooo much to everyone, this helped me a lot, now I get it!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not built into PHP, but like @SLaks said, it's usually for translation. When a different language file is used, it will look through that file for the translation of infoBookingsTitle and show that instead. Usually the __() function will return the string, and the _e() function will echo it.

```
<?php
echo __('Hello');
_e(' World');

// Result: "Hello World" will be displayed, unless a translation file is available
```

Comment: Thank you soooo much, now I get it!!